# Не получается сделать блоки одинаковой высоты с помощью flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Привет. Прошу вашей помощи. Хочу сделать так, чтобы заголовки были одинаковой высоты вне зависимости от кол-ва текста. Смотрю в сторону flexbox, но мои попытки сделать так, как мне нужно не дали результата. Вот примеры моего кода. Спасибо!

```css
.row
{

 margin-left: -(map-get($grid-column-gutter, medium) / 2);
 margin-right: -(map-get($grid-column-gutter, medium) / 2);
 @include clearfix;
 

 @for $i from 1 through 4
 {
  @include grid-layout(#{$i}, '.grid-#{$i}', $grid-column-gutter);  
 }

 [class^="grid"]
 {
  display: flex;
  a
  {
   display: block;
   background: #ccc;

   .product-title
   {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: rem-calc(10 0);
    background: green;

    h2
    {
     background: cyan;
     line-height: 19px;
     font-weight: 700;
     /*height: 50px;*/
     flex: 1 1 auto;

    }
   }

   .product-meta
   {
    @include clearfix;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: rem-calc(10 0);
    padding-bottom: rem-calc(10);

    .price-new
    {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #000;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
        <div class="row">

          <div class="grid-3">
            <a href="#">
              <div class="product-preview">
                <img src="http://keroline.ru/UserFiles/Image/ (639)s.jpg" alt="Костюм с длинной юбкой">
              </div>

              <div class="product-title">
                <h2>lorem</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="product-meta">
                <span class="price-new">
                  800
                  <span class="rubznak">
                    р
                  </span>
                </span>

                <button class="addToWishList" style="float:right; border: none; padding: 0; margin-right: 15px;" role="button" data-uid="261">wish</button>
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="addToCartList addToCartListMainPage" data-num="1" data-uid="261" data-cart="В корзине">                    
                To cart
              </button>

            </a>
          </div>


          <div class="grid-3">
            <a href="#">
              <div class="product-preview">
                <img src="http://keroline.ru/UserFiles/Image/ (639)s.jpg" alt="Костюм с длинной юбкой">
              </div>

              <div class="product-title">
                <h2>lorem7</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="product-meta">
                <span class="price-new">
                  800
                  <span class="rubznak">
                    р
                  </span>
                </span>

                <button class="addToWishList" style="float:right; border: none; padding: 0; margin-right: 15px;" role="button" data-uid="261">wish</button>
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="addToCartList addToCartListMainPage" data-num="1" data-uid="261" data-cart="В корзине">                    
                To cart
              </button>

            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-3">
            <a href="#">
              <div class="product-preview">
                <img src="http://keroline.ru/UserFiles/Image/ (639)s.jpg" alt="Костюм с длинной юбкой">
              </div>

              <div class="product-title">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi in corporis tempora dolores maiores animi.</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="product-meta">
                <span class="price-new">
                  800
                  <span class="rubznak">
                    р
                  </span>
                </span>

                <button class="addToWishList" style="float:right; border: none; padding: 0; margin-right: 15px;" role="button" data-uid="261">wish</button>
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="addToCartList addToCartListMainPage" data-num="1" data-uid="261" data-cart="В корзине">                    
                To cart
              </button>

            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image: пример]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex - правильное направление для решения, просто используйте flex-grow, если динамический элемент только один на item.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.image {
  flex-basis: 40vh;
  background: red;
}
.item {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-basis: 20%;
 flex-grow: 0;
 background: lightgray;
}
.header {
  background: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1; /* <----- здесь */
}
.button {
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="header">Header short</div>
    <div class="price">10c</div>
    <div class="button">to cart</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="header">Header Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="price">10c</div>
    <div class="button">to cart</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="header">Header short</div>
    <div class="price">10c</div>
    <div class="button">to cart</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="header">Header short</div>
    <div class="price">10c</div>
    <div class="button">to cart</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

для случая с несколькими динамическими элементами подойдет grid или просто table.

ps: в сниппет лучше вставлять как-то работающий код.