# Заверстать блоки одинаковой высоты

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block">
    <div class="sub-block-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?</div>
    <div class="sub-block-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, quia labore?</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="sub-block-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
    <div class="sub-block-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, mollitia aperiam corrupti repudiandae aut beatae quae hic odio recusandae quidem eum ipsa similique cupiditate consequatur.</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="sub-block-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam dolores quae ratione, delectus exercitationem facilis magnam, modi alias deleniti consectetur eum in aspernatur ex at commodi debitis sequi. Accusamus, sit.</div>
    <div class="sub-block-2">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="sub-block-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
    <div class="sub-block-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, natus.</div>
</div>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block{
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub-block-1{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Есть вот такая верстка. Можно ли серым блокам задать одинаковую высоту на чистом css, с учетом того, что `sub-block-1` и `sub-block-2` в каждом из div `block` имеют разную длину контента?

Comment: Разметка обязательно должна оставаться такой же?

Comment: да, но если есть альтернатива - предлагайте

Comment: Почти, но у меня sub-block-2 имеет тоже динамическое количество контента

Answer (score 1):

Если все-таки можно менять разметку, то легко реализуется даже с меньшим количеством дивов. Так же можно использовать и [CSS Grid](https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide). Если задача именно сделать одинаковыми внутри, то без JS никак. Можно конечно задать `min-height`, но это будет не универсальное решение.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.block--gray {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block block--gray">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block block--gray">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block block--gray">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block block--gray">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, vero?
    </div>
</div>
```

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается сделать блоки одинаковой
>   высоты с помощью flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641118/).

Не является, так как там у картинки задана явная высота.

Comment: *не является дубликатом потому, что у картинка явная высота* - есть картинка или нет, разницы [нет](http://jsfiddle.net/a3t6wdyn/) в дубликате была просьба сделать [заголовки одной высоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641118/)